# Unknown reason for java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, spring, struts2, struts2-convention-plugin, struts2-spring-plugin

In an application, we have declared `Action` class as a Spring bean. This is working fine for all Struts mapping.

```xml
<bean id="plantAdminApprovalAction" scope="prototype"
        class="com.honda.naps.action.padmin.PlantAdminApprovalAction">
        <constructor-arg ref="plantAdminAppController" />
        <property name="plantAdminApprovalDTO" ref="plantAdminApprovalDTO"></property>
</bean>
```

We are using this for multiple Struts mapping

```xml
<action name="loadApprovalPlant" class="plantAdminApprovalAction" method="loadNAPSApprovalScreenFinal" >
    <result name="success" type="tiles">ApprovalWorkflowPlant</result>
</action>
<action name="loadMandatoryApprovalScreenFinal" class="plantAdminApprovalAction" method="loadMandatoryApprovalScreenFinal" >
    <result name="success" type="tiles">MandatoryApprovalWorkflowPlant</result>
</action>
<action name="deleteTransportApprover" class="plantAdminApprovalAction" method="deleteTransportApprover">
    <result name="success" type="tiles">ApprovalWorkflowPlant</result>
</action>
<action name="deleteApprover" class="plantAdminApprovalAction" method="deleteApprover">
    <result name="success" type="redirect-action">loadMandatoryApprovalScreenFinal</result>
</action>
<action name="insertApprover" class="plantAdminApprovalAction" method="insertApprover">
    <result name="success">/jsps/padmin/addApproverMsg.jsp</result>
</action>
<action name="addNonMandateDepartment" class="plantAdminApprovalAction" method="addNonMandateDepartment">
    <result name="success">/jsps/padmin/addDepartment.jsp</result>
</action>
<action name="insertDeptApprover" class="plantAdminApprovalAction" method="insertDeptApprover">
    <result name="success">/jsps/padmin/addnonmandeptMsg.jsp</result>
</action>
<action name="addApprover" class="plantAdminApprovalAction" method="addApprover">
    <result name="success">/jsps/padmin/addApprover.jsp</result>
</action>
<action name="deleteDeptApprover" class="plantAdminApprovalAction" method="deleteDepartmentApprovers">
    <result name="success" type="redirect-action">loadApprovalPlant</result>
</action>
```

At all action mapping declaration it is working fine but one declaration it is breaking and throwing below exception:

```
2015-08-11 05:02:04,843  ERROR com.honda.naps.interceptor.NAPSCustomExceptionInterceptor (NAPSLogger.java:141) -  Line Number: 141 ---> Entering exception handler logic.
java.lang.RuntimeException: Invalid action class configuration that references an unknown class named [PlantAdminApprovalAction]
    at org.apache.struts2.convention.ConventionsServiceImpl.determineResultPath(ConventionsServiceImpl.java:100)
    at org.apache.struts2.convention.ConventionUnknownHandler.determinePath(ConventionUnknownHandler.java:385)
    at org.apache.struts2.convention.ConventionUnknownHandler.handleUnknownResult(ConventionUnknownHandler.java:274)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultUnknownHandlerManager.handleUnknownResult(DefaultUnknownHandlerManager.java:87)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.createResult(DefaultActionInvocation.java:226)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.executeResult(DefaultActionInvocation.java:367)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:277)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:263)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:68)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:133)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:207)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:207)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:190)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.MultiselectInterceptor.intercept(MultiselectInterceptor.java:75)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:94)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:314)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:100)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:141)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:142)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:166)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:176)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:190)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    at com.honda.naps.interceptor.NAPSCustomExceptionInterceptor.intercept(NAPSCustomExceptionInterceptor.java:54)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:52)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:485)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:77)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:91)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:190)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:125)
    at com.honda.naps.filter.ClipGZipFilter.doFilter(ClipGZipFilter.java:121)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:190)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:125)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:368)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:109)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:97)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:78)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:35)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.java:89)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:79)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:169)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:237)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:190)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:125)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain._doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:80)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:908)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:997)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.extension.DefaultExtensionProcessor.invokeFilters(DefaultExtensionProcessor.java:1078)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.extension.DefaultExtensionProcessor.handleRequest(DefaultExtensionProcessor.java:998)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3954)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:276)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:942)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1592)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:186)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:453)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:515)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:306)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:83)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1646)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: PlantAdminApprovalAction
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:434)
    at com.ibm.ws.bootstrap.ExtClassLoader.findClass(ExtClassLoader.java:191)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:660)
    at com.ibm.ws.bootstrap.ExtClassLoader.loadClass(ExtClassLoader.java:111)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:626)
    at com.ibm.ws.classloader.ProtectionClassLoader.loadClass(ProtectionClassLoader.java:62)
    at com.ibm.ws.classloader.ProtectionClassLoader.loadClass(ProtectionClassLoader.java:58)
    at com.ibm.ws.classloader.CompoundClassLoader.loadClass(CompoundClassLoader.java:511)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:626)
    at com.ibm.ws.classloader.CompoundClassLoader.loadClass(CompoundClassLoader.java:511)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:626)
    at org.apache.struts2.util.ClassLoaderUtils.loadClass(ClassLoaderUtils.java:111)
    at org.apache.struts2.convention.ConventionsServiceImpl.determineResultPath(ConventionsServiceImpl.java:98)
    ... 97 more
```

Unfortunately, this is not happening on Eclipse and Test environment but it is happening on QA environment. Need some thoughts and inputs for this issue.

Comment: Which version of S2 you are using? Which exact action doesn't work?

Comment: With S2 spring plugin using bean id in struts.xml action class attribute should work.

Comment: @Aleksandr M can you please provide the plugin's fullname? I believe, this should be the updated jar file.

Comment: http://struts.apache.org/docs/spring-plugin.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: PlantAdminApprovalAction

It expects a valid class name (FQCN) to be used for the action class. For example

```xml
<action name="loadApprovalPlant" class="com.honda.naps.action.padmin.PlantAdminApprovalAction" method="loadNAPSApprovalScreenFinal" >
    <result name="success" type="tiles">ApprovalWorkflowPlant</result>
</action>
```

Comment: Thanks for providing the steps. Can you give me the step wise code snippet? This will give more clarity to me and whoever read your answer.